# raspberry pi reading serial data from arduino via c++

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port, usb, raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to read serial data from my arduino on my raspberry pi via C++.
When i try to run my code the first value get's read fine but on the second value i get al sorts of weird numbers between 0 and 255.
I tried the code on my macbook and it works fine.

Iam running my code on a raspberry pi 2b+ the arduino is connected via usb.

Arduino code:

```
unsigned char pots[2];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  pots[0] = analogRead(0) / 8 | 128;
  pots[1] = analogRead(1) / 8;


  Serial.write(pots,2);  
  delay(1);
}
```

C++ code:

```
FILE *file;
unsigned char doorspoelChar;
const char *devicename="/dev/cu.usbmodem1421";

int potParams[2];


int main()
{
  file=fopen(devicename,"r");

  if(file==NULL){
    printf("Unable to open device %s\n",devicename);
    exit(1);
  }

  do{

    do{
      fread(&doorspoelChar,1,1,file);
    } while (doorspoelChar < 128);


    potParams[0] = doorspoelChar & 127;
    fread(&doorspoelChar,1,1,file);

    potParams[1] = doorspoelChar ;
    fread(&doorspoelChar,1,1,file);

    std::cout << potParams[0] << " " << potParams[1] << "\n";

  }while(1);

}
```